# NumericUpDown control for Percentages?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, controls, numericupdown

How can I set a NumericUpDown control to display values as percentages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to derive your own custom control and override the `UpdateEditText()` method.  While we're at it, let's override the default `Minimum`, `Maximum`, and `Increment` property values to be a little more percentage-friendly.

We'll also need to override the base `ParseEditText()` method to interpret the user-generated input as a percentage (dividing by 100), because the user will expect to enter `80` to represent `80%` (and the Decimal parser needs to ignore the percentage sign).

```
Public Class PercentUpDown
    Inherits NumericUpDown

    Private Shared ReadOnly DefaultValue As New [Decimal](0.0)      ' 0%
    Private Shared ReadOnly DefaultMinimum As New [Decimal](0.0)    ' 0%
    Private Shared ReadOnly DefaultMaximum As New [Decimal](1.0)    ' 100%
    Private Shared ReadOnly DefaultIncrement As New [Decimal](0.01) ' 1%

    Public Sub New()
        Value = DefaultValue
        Minimum = DefaultMinimum
        Maximum = DefaultMaximum
        Increment = DefaultIncrement
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub UpdateEditText()
        If UserEdit Then
            ParseEditText()
        End If

        Text = Value.ToString(String.Format("p{0}", DecimalPlaces))
    End Sub

    Protected Shadows Sub ParseEditText()
        Debug.Assert(UserEdit = True, "ParseEditText() - UserEdit == false")

        Try
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text) AndAlso _
               Not (Text.Length = 1 AndAlso Text.Equals("-")) Then

                Value = Constrain(Decimal.Parse(Text.Replace("%", String.Empty), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) / 100)

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Leave value as it is
        Finally
            UserEdit = False
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function Constrain(origValue As [Decimal]) As [Decimal]
        Debug.Assert(Minimum <= Maximum, "minimum > maximum")

        If origValue < Minimum Then Return Minimum
        If origValue > Maximum Then Return Maximum

        Return origValue
    End Function

End Class
```

We could expand the scope of the class a little by adding a `TextFormat` property where we could set the [numeric display format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) we'd like to use at design time, so that we can support displaying the value as a Currency, for example.

The above code, though, is nice and compact and specifically targets Percentages, taking advantage of the existing `DecimalPlaces` property.  The `Value` property is stored as the mathematical representation of the percentage (0.5 for 50%, for example), so it's simple to plug into a formula without worrying about dividing by 100.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy answer to this question: use [`DecimalUpDown`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DecimalUpDown) from the Extended WPF Toolkit, instead of [`NumericUpDown`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown) (it should be noted that NumericUpDown is listed as obsolete as well). All you need to do then is set `Maximum="1" Minimum="0.01" Increment="0.01" FormatString="P0"` in the XAML. I'm assuming that this question is about the Extended WPF Toolkit, as the answer above is for it.

Example:

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown Maximum="1" Minimum="0.01" Value="0.01" Increment="0.01" FormatString="P0" />
```

Displays:

[image: DecimalUpDown Example]

Comment: The question and the accepted answer are both WinForm issues.